# CORS Issue After Adding Sentry Monitoring to my .net 7 API project

Tags: c#, cors, sentry, .net-7.0

I uninstalled Sentry version 3.41.3 from my .NET 7 API project and configured Sentry using a separate class as follows:

```
namespace Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
{
    public static class ExceptionMonitoringServices
    {
        public static void AddExceptionMonitoringServices(this IServiceCollection services, ConfigurationManager configuration)
        {
            SentrySdk.Init(options =>
            {
                options.Dsn = configuration.GetValue<string>("Sentry:Dsn");
                options.Debug = configuration.GetValue<bool>("Sentry:Debug");

                options.AttachStacktrace = configuration.GetValue<bool>("Sentry:AttachStackTrace");
                options.StackTraceMode = configuration.GetValue<StackTraceMode>("Sentry:StackTraceMode");
                options.IsGlobalModeEnabled = configuration.GetValue<bool>("Sentry:IsGlobalModeEnabled");
                options.DiagnosticLevel = configuration.GetValue<SentryLevel>("Sentry:DiagnosticsLevel");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I then added the Sentry configuration to my Program.cs using:

```
builder.Services.AddExceptionMonitoringServices(builder.Configuration);
```

However, after this configuration, all my APIs started experiencing CORS issues. It's worth noting that the CORS configuration was already set in the project using the following code:

```
// Configure CORS
var allowedOrigins = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("AllowedOrigins").Split(';');
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddDefaultPolicy(builder =>
    {
        builder.WithOrigins(allowedOrigins)
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod();
    });
});
```

The exact error message is:

> "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'XXXX' from origin 'XXX' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

Any assistance in resolving this CORS problem would be greatly appreciated. Honestly, I verified everything that I could check, but nothing worked.

Comment: What is the stored value for key "AllowedOrigins" ?

Comment: The 'AllowedOrigins' key contains a semicolon-separated list of domains that utilize my APIs. Prior to integrating Sentry (SentrySdk.Init), the CORS configuration was functioning as expected. However, after adding Sentry, CORS-related issues arose. The 'AllowedOrigins' list includes all the domains that were previously working seamlessly with the APIs.

Comment: @HamzaBenTiba Origin != domain. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Origin